# SQL Server, first of each time series

Tags: sql-server

A table 'readings' has a list of dates

```
[Date]                [Value]
2015-03-19 00:30:00     1.2
2015-03-19 00:40:00     1.2
2015-03-19 00:50:00     0.1
2015-03-19 01:00:00     0.1
2015-03-19 01:10:00     2
2015-03-19 01:20:00     0.5
2015-03-19 01:30:00     0.5
```

I need to get the most recent instance where the value is below a set point (in this case the value 1.0), but I only want the start (earliest datetime) where the value was below 1 for consecutive times.
So with the above data I want to return 2015-03-19 01:20:00, as the most recent block of times where value < 1, but I want the start of that block.

This SQL just returns the most recent date, rather than the first date whilst the value has been low (so returns 2015-03-19 01:30:00 )

```
select top 1 *
from readings where value <=1
order by [date] desc
```

I can't work out how to group the consecutive dates, to therefore only get the first ones

It is SQL Server, the real data isn't at exactly ten min intervals, and the readings table is about 70,000 rows- so fairly large!

Thanks, Charli

Comment: What about this `('2015-03-19 00:50:00',  0.1)` record? Here value is below 1 and date is earlier than `2015-03-19 01:20:00`.

Comment: Updated the question slightly, I need the most recent block of consecutive dates where [Value] < 1, but the earliest datetime in that block

Comment: Have a look at the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f55555/1)

```
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [Date]
        ,Value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cast([Date] AS DATE) ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS RN FROM @table WHERE value <= 1
    ) t WHERE t.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Max( [date] )
From [dbo].[readings]
Where ( [value] <= 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the minimum date for each set of *consecutive* records having a value that is less than 1. The query below returns exactly these dates:

```
SELECT MIN([Date])
FROM (
  SELECT [Date], [Value], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) -
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [Value] < 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE Value < 1
GROUP BY grp
```

`grp` calculated field identifies *consecutive* records having `Value<1`.

**Note:** The above query will work for SQL Server 2012+.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42c0d/4)

**Edit:**

To get the date value of the *last* group you can modify the above query to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MIN([Date])
FROM (
  SELECT [Date], [Value], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) -
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [Value] < 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE Value < 1
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42c0d/5)

Comment: I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 right now, just trying to find a 2012 database I could use instead!